# how can i install facebook SDK to my visual studio 2010 without github?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I want to use Facebook SDK with my asp.net website which has Facebook log in 
iam using visual studio 2010
git hub is not user friendly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the c-sharp SDK of facebook using NuGet. Github is just a hoster for gitprojects. It is just a matter of time to understand GIT. If u understand how github works u know how to pull projects.

There is also a ZIP button to easily download the projects as a ZIP.

- http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook

Or download it using the ZIP button of github.

- https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk